# Rate-limiting with Kong Gateway based on the return HTTP status code other than 200

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, rate-limiting, kong

I need to limit the number of calls to a single API based on the return HTTP status code with Kong.

For example, if the API repeatedly returns a response other than 200, more requests to this API must be restricted.

I've been going through various articles and blogs but couldn't find any workable solution except **Response rate-limit plugin** within Kong.
Kindly advise whether this plugin is a right choice for my requirement or is there any solution.

Please keep in mind that this is my first post in this forum, and please let me know if there are any errors or corrections.